# Can I freelance if I know only HTML,CSS and Javascript?

Tags: freelance-websites, working-from-home, price-per-hour, web-development

I cannot use Photoshop, cannot create images, don't have any knowledge of backend languages.
Can I freelance with the available skills? How do I start?what should be my wage given that I'm a beginer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surely freelance using those skills. But, given the condition,I cannot foresee a clientbase with pretty nice cash inflow towards your side.

Generally, with these skills, you will be getting clients who need portfolio/static websites. That too, depends on how you bag these clients.

Getting more knowledge on Wordpress and other CMSes will help you to gain some stability on this domain.

You have to start by reaching out to people online/offline who need a website made.

Your wage depends on you. What is the bare minimum amount for you (per hour or fixed), depending on the project.

Your top priority should be to get this amount at any cost. Above that, whatever your charge the client is totally your talent.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Your location and your personality /confidence is as much if not more important than what you know.

A freelancer is sometimes called a consultant or a contractor. All are service providers.

A company will expect a service provider to undertake a responsibility for a task or project. They are not interested in giving you experience or a test and paying you to learn. If you are too cheap, well, if something is too good to be true, it usually is and many companies will avoid you. If you too expensive they will move on to. Your charge rate depends on location. Because your skills have alit to do with design most clients would want you onsite. Working from remote leaves huge area for what you believe the client wants and what they expect.

A prior q&a I answered should help https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/how-to-build-a-startup-freelance-software-qa-in-the-us/8585#8585

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do with only these skills, including:

1. Making a static website
2. Setting up a WordPress website (no programming required)
3. Conducting user experience testing
4. Managing a blog
5. Doing social media marketing